# Lebesgue integral of non-zero function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let's say that $f$ is a characteristic function such that $f \neq 0$. I have a certain measure $\mu$. Can I conclude that the Lebesgue integral $\int f d\mu \neq 0$ and why or why not?

Comment: If $f$ is the characteristic function of some measurable set $E$, then $\int f d\mu$ will be nonzero if and only if $\mu(E) > 0$.

Comment: so, basically you are saying that this statement is true? What about @Yanko's answer below then?

Comment: No, the statement is not true. There are many nonempty sets $E$ with measure zero, and for each of those sets, the characteristic function $\chi_E$ is not the zero function but has integral zero. For the simplest example, let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure and let $E$ be a set containing a single point, say $E = \{0\}$.

Comment: By the way, if $\mu$ happens to be a measure that is nonzero for all nonempty sets (for example, counting measure), then the conclusion **is** true. But for general measures, it's not.

Comment: In case it's not clear, note that for a characteristic function $\chi_E$, the integral $\int \chi_E\ d\mu$ is exactly equal to $\mu(E)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If $C$ is the [cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), $f$ is the characteristic function for $C$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ then
$$\int f dx = \mu(C)=0$$

Comment: I should also note that the zero functions is always a characteristic function for the empty set, this function's integral is zero independently on the choice of the measure.

Comment: this goes a bit far for me, as I'm not familiar with the Cantor set but I'll think about it ...

Comment: @Daniel Ok, the cantor set is a standard example of a non-trivial set whose measure is zero. Instead I could take any finite set, say $C=\{0\}$. The characteristic function of this $C$ is the function taking $1$ at the point $0$ and $0$ everywhere else. This function's integral is zero.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!